# WPF C# ComboBox and DataGrid display all and not one result

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have made DB with a table and 2 fields on that table. ID and Name SQL Server.
My WPF Application has a combo box and i bind the Table.Name to the combobox.
Then i bind a DataGrid to the Table itself.

So what i have is when choosing an item on the combobox on the datagrid i get is as "selected", i wish it to display on the item i choose.

Thanks

e.g picture below, i choose first, but i want only the data of first to be displayed and not selected.[image]

Comment: Did you mean to show the ComboBox Data Object in the Grid in details (like showing more properties other than DisplayName) or filtering some other Object Collection based on the selection ?

Comment: is there only one item in respect with combobox selected item. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the table to your combobox and then bind the datagrid to the combobox.SelectedItem
I don't have a xaml editor but you will have something like this:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo_MyCbo" ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" DisplaMemberPath="Name">
    <!--DataTemplate If Needed-->
</ComboBox>
<Datagrid x:Name="dtg_MyDtg" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbo_MyCbo, Path=SelectedItem}">
    <!-- column def-->
</Datagrid>
```